# Search if providing id is exist on Multiple objects under array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My Database having this value

```
id: ObjectId(6a00683bac41ce1054774e7d),
currentuserid: "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e36",
dataset: Array
 0: Object
   userid: "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e37"

 1: Object
   userid: "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e38"

2: Object
   userid: "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e39"
```

Now I want to make query which first Check That "currentuserid" is Exist under array. if Value exist then returns true else false. I am new in mongodb. I also read **$in Operator** . My query is

```
Mydata.find({ dataset: { $in: [{userid: '69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e36'}] } }, function(req, res){
  if(err){ console.log('Not Matched'); }
  else{ console.log('Matched') }
});
```

But i am unable to achieve it

Comment: `.find({ "dataset.userid": '69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e36' })`. `$in` is meant for an "array of arguments" NOT for "checking arrays". MongoDB could not care less that the value is in an array. All it needs is the correct "path".

Comment: So how can I achieve this Sir?

Comment: By using the exact query I actually gave you. Read ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and understand why. Keep reading all the tutorials on querying while you are there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Mydata.findOne({dataset:{$elemMatch:{userid:'69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e37'}}},function(err, data){
  if(err){ 
    throw err; 
  } else if(data){ 
    console.log('Matched');
  }else{
    console.log('Not Matched')
  }  
});
```

It will result data as null for userid **69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e36**.

Comment: No it will not like that. It always runs on both cases i.e "Matched"

Comment: My document structure was as follow: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a02e6bb6a0755f9e9aac29c"),
    "currentuserid" : "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e36",
    "dataset" : [ 
        {
            "userid" : "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e37"
        }, 
        {
            "userid" : "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e38"
        }, 
        {
            "userid" : "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e39"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: May be Something like:

var _userId = "69fc06dbf88c8c15042b4e36"
Mydata.findOne({currentuserid: _userId, dataset:{$elemMatch:{userid:_userId}}},function(err, data){
  if(err){ 
    throw err; 
  } else if(data){ 
    console.log('Matched');
  }else{
    console.log('Not Matched')
  }  
});